# Unable to Launch Octane RoadRunner Server for PHP 8.0

Tags: php, laravel, go, octane, roadrunner

Octane is installed with roadrunner while following the [official guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/octane), on the `Ubuntu 18.04` server. Each step works as expected until the server is started:

`php artisan octane:start --server=roadrunner --port=8181`

Then, an error is received and the command exits. The complete stacktrace is attached:

```
   INFO  Server running…

  Local: http://127.0.0.1:8181 

  Press Ctrl+C to stop the server


   INFO  [INFO] RoadRunner server started; version: 2.6.3, buildtime: 2021-12-03T11:37:00+0000
PHP Warning:  require(/path/vendor/bin/bootstrap.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/vendor/bin/roadrunner-worker on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/path/vendor/bin/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /path/vendor/bin/roadrunner-worker:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /path/vendor/bin/roadrunner-worker on line 18


   INFO  error occurred: WorkerAllocate:

   INFO     goridge_frame_receive: EOF, plugin: http.Plugin

   ERROR  2021-12-07T12:01:53.048Z  ERROR   container/poller.go:16  vertex got an error {"id": "http.Plugin", "error": "WorkerAllocate:\n\tgoridge_frame_receive: EOF"}

   ERROR  github.com/spiral/endure/pkg/container.(*Endure).poll.func1

   ERROR    github.com/spiral/endure@v1.0.10/pkg/container/poller.go:16

   ERROR  handle_serve_command: WorkerAllocate:

   ERROR    goridge_frame_receive: EOF
```

Since roadrunner is based on go, I don't have much insights on how to navigate through the error. Please let me know if anyone has solved this issue before, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix all warnings like this one: `PHP Warning:  require(/path/vendor/bin/bootstrap.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/vendor/bin/roadrunner-worker on line 18`

These warnings appear in the `stdout`, but `stdout` is used as a process fd to communicate with the RR. That means if some data is sent to the `stdout` (like PHP warning) before RR initializes all processes (aka worker), RR will stop allocating the workers and exit with code 1.